# Dynamic datatable Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I would like to know how could I make a data table row with Dynamic data.
I have this table:

[image]

But I want to show the red data dynamically according to my user roles.

For example if my role is equal to supervisor show him one buttons or if my role is different to this one show to user other buttons

this is my html table:

```
    <div class="table-responsive-lg table-responsive-md">
        <table id="table" class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>  
                    <th>Solicitante</th>
                    <th>Dia de solicitud</th>
                    <th>Estatus</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

And I call this method in document ready function

```
             table = $('#table').DataTable({
                  'data': data
                , 'columns': [
                    {
                        'className': 'details-control',
                        'orderable': false,
                        'data': null,
                        'defaultContent': ''
                    },
                    { 'data': 'name' },
                    { 'data': 'request.dateRquest' },
                    { 'data': 'request.status' },
                    {
                    "className": '',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": '<button class= "btn btn-success btn-circle asignar" title="Asignar"> <i class="material-icons">assignment_ind</i></button>'+
                        "&nbsp;"+
                        '<button class= "btn btn-danger btn-circle rechazar" title="Rechazar"> <i class="material-icons">close</i></button>'
                    }
                ],
                'order': [[1, 'asc']]
             })
```

Can I iterate the data that i want to put on my table? In the picture I have a column call estatus if the estatus is different to pending I want to make other action with the button.

So I need to check the role of person that is sign in and check the status of each row

I want to make someting like this:

If(role == xRole && data.status != 'Pending'){
Change style of button 
Put a different class for example change .Assign to .CloseRequest
}

If I knew how to interactue with the data that I'm going to put in the rows before the table was maked it will be more easy

It is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
                "defaultContent": '<button class= "btn btn-success btn-circle asignar" title="Asignar"> <i class="material-icons">assignment_ind</i></button>'+
                    "&nbsp;"+
                    '<button class= "btn btn-danger btn-circle rechazar" title="Rechazar"> <i class="material-icons">close</i></button>'
```

to

```
                "defaultContent": getButtons()
```

and define this function:

```
function getButtons() {
    switch (role) {
        case "admin": return "sometemplate1";
        default: return "sometemplate2";
    }
}
```

just make sure that `role` is properly defined.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question. Can you help me with this one?

Comment: @JohnatanDeLeon you are welcome. Let me take a look.

Comment: @JohnatanDeLeon you can do the iteration you intend to accomplish by implementing initComplete. See more here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete